# Change active state of list item which imported via angular ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and trying to find if there is a solution to my problem.

I have a list Item created as a partial.html and I need to Import this partial.html in my different pages. 
But this list should have different active state for different pages. Something like a  menu bar.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item active">Item 1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

But as I am importing this list using ng-include in different pages How can I Change active class so that it's on another item.

```
 <ng-include src="'partial.html'"></ng-include>
```

For Example:

1. If I import partial.html to Demo-page-1.html Item 1 should have
   active class.
2. Again if I import partial.html to Demo-page-2.html Item 2 should
   have active class

Is this possible to achieve ? Also for your  Information I am not doing one page app so I have multiple pages. Any information/help will be appreciated.

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to use `ng-include`, don't do it. Instead use a directive. I suspect you haven't learned about this yet since you are new but you should read up on it now. Also, looks like you havent learned about `ng-repeat` yet either - another important topic.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know using ng-repeat but  not about directives much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the project I'm working on, we have pretty much the same issue - a main page with some dropdowns, but a number of partials that are modified by whatever you select from those dropdowns.

What we did was we created what I like to call, the 'Service Pass-through Hack'.  The way this works, is to *abuse* the fact that services under the hood are singletons.

Start with a service:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').factory('someSvc', [someSvc]);

    function someSvc () {
        return {
           // Variables, functions...
        };
    }
})();
```

...Then, in our controller, we both included the service as a dependency, but also exposed it...

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').controller('someCtrl', ['someSvc', someCtrl]);

    function someCtrl(someSvc) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.someSvc = someSvc;
        // Other instance variables...

        // Other functions...
    }
})();
```

Then, we had our markup refer to the service pass-through we created on the controller:

```
<body ng-controller='someCtrl as vm'>
    <select ng-model='vm.someSvc.someProperty' />

    <div ng-include='somePartial.html'></div>
</body>
```

This is something of a mixed bag of good and bad.

**The Good:**

1. You're using singletons as intended - to introduce global scope, thus allowing different partials to cooperate happily.
2. How JavaScript handles a given child value (reference or value) no longer matters - because the service is an object, it will always be passed by reference.
3. Normally, between a service and a controller to pass values, you'd have to tell the service and controller to share values at certain times, either by doing an assignment operator or by calling a method of some kind to synchronize state.  In this setup, because the service is a exposed property of the controller, you don't have to do *any* of that.

**The Bad:**

1. You're using singletons period - to introduce global scope.  This has maintenance ramifications.
2. You're somewhat circumventing the controller; some of your business logic will now wind up in the service you've defined to introduce that global scope, adding to the maintenance issues.
3. You're operating with one giant object reference - anything you change will affect the other use contexts.  Be careful.

In my team's case, due to how JavaScript handles different implicit 'types' (primitives pass by value, objects and arrays pass by reference), we had to go with this route.  While it will work, it can get interesting to maintain.

I **highly** suggest you consider whether or not your app's specific architecture can be modified such that you can still use partials, but not have to do the service pass-through hack I've shown here.

Comment: Hopefully it serves as inspiration for a better solution.  While the situation I'm working with practically requires this approach, that's not to say that a better one doesn't exist.  As you can see, the downsides slightly outweigh the positives of this approach (the upsides being, 'it works'.)  If you find a better way to do this sort of thing, please post it as an answer!